# Best Practice : HTTP Handlers or ActionFilters for Optimal performance

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I use some HTTP Handlers from my Web Forms days forms, to for example Generate Images Thumbnails, Serving CSS, Etc...

I like them, they are easy to make and offer great abstraction.  Can I still use them with optimal performance in MVC or should I use Action Filters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Action Filters add several more layers of abstraction, because they go thru routing and MVC handler. If you are THAT concerned about performance and don't need any MVC features, you should stick to Handlers.

Comment: damn sorry i missed that you got +1

Answer (score 1):

If you want perfomance - use HttpHandlers

If you want testability - use ActionFilters

Personally I prefere ActionFilters where it is possible in ASP.NET MVC